# Listen for an URL to open in kiosk mode on a device

Tags: android

Android device is in front of customer while employee is behind it on computer where he needs to send URL of web page that will be opened for customer to view/review on tablet.

What is yours suggested programming approach to get desired functionality?

Comment: Why You need Kiosk mode for that?

Comment: Why do you need an employee behind a computer? It could be done automatically, by using a database.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose specifically Android provide a option. Only problem is that its supported above Android 6.0 Marshmallow.

Procedure is called Setting up *Single Purpose device* or *corporate-owned, single-use (COSU) device*
For this You need to enable Lock task mode like below example:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:lockTaskMode="if_whitelisted">
```

For full details check this [link](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu).